# Как в centos 7 войти в работающую службу, чтобы смотреть, что она выводит в реальном времени?

Tags: linux, centos

У меня запущен php файл в службе. Как смотреть, что она выводит в реальном времени?

Сама служба:

```
[Unit]
Description = making network connection up
After = network.target
[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/my.php
[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Comment: `sudo journalctl -u <your service unit name>` если вы не настроили по-другому, то обычно логи можно вытащить из journalctl

Comment: лучше еще показать файл сервис юнита. приложите к вопросу

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Добавил

Comment: sudo journalctl -u выводит только notice ошибки

Comment: я предлагаю заменить на `/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/my.php > /var/log/php.log`

Answer (score 0):

Просмотр записей по идентификатору процесса

```
 journalctl _PID=19487
 journalctl -f _PID=19487
```

---

```
journalctl -u nginx.service (nginx.service -  <your service unit name> )
```

Comment: Выводятся только ошибки. Тот же echo или print не выводится